# Storing Date in Sqlitedatabase using date picker and set alarm that matches the current date

Tags: android, date

---

i have successfully stored some data in a Date format by concatenating getDay ,getMonth and getYear then save it in a single field ..when i retrieve it,it looks like this "15/05/2016" ,i have tried to use some logic like using a query but still did not work,is it possible to use a query and create an if statement that if it's equal to the Current Date the Alarm or notification will trigger?or in some other way may be..thanks in advance..

### This is how i save it

```
    int qty1=Integer.parseInt(QTY1.getText().toString());
    String day = String.valueOf(datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
    String getDay=day;
    String month = String.valueOf(datePicker.getMonth() + 1);
    String getMonth=month;
    String year = String.valueOf(datePicker.getYear());
    String getYear=year;
    int remind=numberPicker.getValue();
    String spin=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    databaseHelperItems =new DatabaseHelperItems(context);
    sqLiteDatabase= databaseHelperItems.getWritableDatabase();
   databaseHelperItems.addInformations(descrip,getDay+"  
   /"+"0"+getMonth+"/"+getYear,remind+"="+spin,qty1+"pcs."
   ,LocTextView,

   sqLiteDatabase);
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"DATA SAVED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    databaseHelperItems.close();
```

---

This is How I Retrieve it and it works fine

---

```
   String today=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
   textView.setText(today);
  String search_date=textView.getText().toString();                           
listDataAdapterItems = new ListDataAdapterItems(getApplicationContext(),        

R.layout.row_layout);            
databaseHelperItems = new DatabaseHelperItems(this);
databaseHelperItems = new DatabaseHelperItems(getApplicationContext());
sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelperItems.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = databaseHelperItems.getExpiryDate(search_date,   

sqLiteDatabase);
    listview.setAdapter(listDataAdapterItems);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

 do{
    String description, month1, qty, remind, locationname;
    int myid;
    myid = cursor.getInt(0);
    description = cursor.getString(1);
    month1 = cursor.getString(2);
    qty = cursor.getString(3);
    remind = cursor.getString(4);
    locationname = cursor.getString(5);
    DataProviderItems dataProviderItems = new  DataProviderItems(String.valueOf(myid) + ".", description, month1, qty, remind,  locationname);
    listDataAdapterItems.add(dataProviderItems);
}while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view,

set a daily alarm and write your logic in receiver class , get the values from data base and check if it equals to current date then show the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the "time" as "long"  type in SQLite,then the query the "time" show it by `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date(time))`.